# I'm a newbie and I'm stuck with this step in my Android Studio Program

Tags: java, android-studio

When I was trying to run the emulator on the paid version ( paidDebug ), instead of running well on the free version, it showed up these things... Can anyone help me to figure out this? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Wdfy.png)

Comment: Please, don't use images of code and errors. [edit] your question and put your code and errors in there as text.

Comment: Also, the error is in your tests, so it would be useful to see the appropriate test as well.

Answer (score -2):

- Clear the Studio Cache memory
- Restart Studio
- Try to run in usual Debug mode
- This will work